# The correct Javascript Date.parse(...) format string?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, string-formatting

What is a culture-invariant way of constructing a string such that the Javascript Date() constructor can parse it and create the proper date object?

I have tried these format strings which don't work (using C# to generate the strings):

```
clientDate.ToString();
// gives: "11/05/2009 17:35:23 +00:00"

clientDate.ToString("MMM' 'dd', 'yyyy' 'h':'mm':'ss' 'tt");
// works on an English server
// but on a French server, gives: "mai 11, 2009 5:35:23"
// Javascript won't parse that.

clientDate.ToString("MM'-'dd'-'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss")
// gives: 05-11-2009 17:35:23
```

What is the universal format??

Comment: good question, this is a tough problem

Comment: Why do you want a single string for that?

Comment: I need to emit a string to the browser so I can then use Javascript to localize the string, using Javascript's toLocaleString() function.  However, I've had difficulty figuring out a successful, single string format that will be emitted by all my servers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[According to MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Given a string representing a time, `parse` returns the time value. It accepts the IETF standard ([RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) Section 5.2.14 and elsewhere) date syntax: `"Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT"`. It understands the continental US time-zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time-zone offset, for example, `"Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0430"` (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian). If you do not specify a time zone, the local time zone is assumed. GMT and UTC are considered equivalent.

If you can’t generate this format using english locale, try to use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: RFC 1123 to the rescue!  Thanks Maciej!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a locale-independent format Javascript can parse, you can use `2013-03-31T16:36:57+0900`. It works at least in Node.js and Chrome, so I suspect it's standard.

Comment: Does not work on Android 2.2 (works on 2.3 and higher). Does not work on any iOS device (tested 5.0 and 6.0).

Comment: How about `2013-03-31T16:36:57Z` then? Works here on iOS. Difference is the time must now be GMT.

Comment: If only it were that simple... That format (it's called ISO-8601) won't work in IE8 either.