# Which should be the correct date format for Date.parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, format

Hey guys, Im having trouble knowing wat is the correct date format i should put for date.parse() function.

I want to use mm/dd/yyyy in the function like this.

```
alert("Date: "+Date.parse("11/28/2011")); 
//-->Its showing me Date:NaN as output.
```

also I wanted to know what output should I be getting if I do this following code:

```
date = Date.parse('12/31/2011' +' UTC');
var minutes=1000*60;
var hours=minutes*60;
var days=hours*24;
var years=days*365;
var y=date/years;
```

t should give me exactly 42 years but its giving me decimal as well. Y so??

Any help will be appreciated guys.

Thanks

Anand

Comment: You didn't take leap years into account in your calculation

Comment: Not only did you not take leap years into your calculations, "12/31/2011" also means midnight (morning) of the last day.  So you're most likely missing 24 hours.

Comment: yea..dint take leap years into account..thx for dat...

Answer (score 2):

International (ISO) standard date time format will always work. `2011-12-31`

You may also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088793/the-correct-javascript-date-parse-format-string)

Comment: Dunno about "universal", but it's an international (ISO) standard and certainly much more widely and consistently supported than the ambiguous format used by the OP.

Comment: Universal is too strong -- this doesn't work in IE6-8. See http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html. In practice you'll have better luck using YYYY/MM/DD.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it give you exactly 42 years? Don't forget that there's no such thing as an exact number of milliseconds in a year, due to leap years (and leap seconds, if they're accounted for). Even if there were, you're getting the start of the last day of 2011, which isn't the same as the start of the first day of 2012, which is probably what you were thinking of.

The exact formats supported are implementation-specific as far as I can tell - at least for ECMAScript (which I realise isn't quite the same as JavaScript).

Comment: yea i was of the impression that exact days divided by 365 will give me exactly 42 yrs but as u rightly pointed out,that aint the case.